# How to append to Map JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have Map:

```
dataMap = new Map<string, string[]>([
    ['Fruits', ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana']],
    ['Vegetables', ['Tomato', 'Potato', 'Onion']],
    ['Apple', ['Fuji', 'Macintosh']],
    ['Onion', ['Yellow', 'White', 'Purple']]
  ]);
```

I tried to append new value by key `Fruits`:

```
dataMap.set("Fruits", "Huaba");
```

To get the following:

```
['Fruits', ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'Huaba']]...
```

What about this solution:

```
append(key: string, value: string[]) {
    let _g = this.dataMap.get(key);
    _g = _g.concat(value);
    this.dataMap.set(key, _g);
  }
```

Comment: The syntax doesn't look correct for JavaScript, it does have built in associative objects which work the same way as maps.  The syntax you have supplied looks similar to C++ or Java.

Comment: @SPlatten what are you talking about? Javascript has Map object 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: @SPlatten JS does have a Map object mate [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Comment: Not formatted or set-up like that it doesn't.

Comment: The only thing that's not JS is the type declaration (`new Map<string, string[]>` should be `new Map`, I guess OP is using Typescript

Comment: @DominikMatis what about this https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/a67c19be85df49fd923b8175beb7f1c75c2e5c24/types/core-js/index.d.ts#L73

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the value and  push the new value and set back

```
dataMap.set("Fruits", ( dataMap.get("Fruits") || [] ).concat('Huaba'));
```

Comment: Could I assign some values as string[]? I mean append `['A', 'B']`?

Comment: @OPV yes you can, the above answer will take care of this case too

Answer (score 3):

You need to get the `Array` and push the new value : `dataMap.get('Fruits').push('Huaba')`

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the previous value + new value, so this should work:

```
dataMap.set("Fruits", [...dataMap.get("Fruits"), "Huaba"]);
```

Comment: Could I assing some values as string[]?

Comment: What do you mean ? Can you write an example ?

Comment: I mean this: `append(key: string, value: string[]) {
    this.dataMap.set(key, [...this.dataMap.get(key), value]);
  }`

Comment: Oh I see, you want to add all strings from `value`, so in that case you should do `this.dataMap.set(key, [...this.dataMap.get(key), ...value])`